# Subdomain caching issue

Tags: caching, dns, subdomain

I have set up a subdomain **abc.mysite.com** to point a specific IP on another server. I did this by creating the following A records:

**abc 300 in A xx.xxx.xx.xx** and **www.abc 300 in A xx.xxx.xx.xx**

My host confirms that this was done correctly, however (3 days later) the domain still resolves intermittently. That is, sometimes it resolves to the correct IP and I see the correct page and other times I see a 404 error or a default website page from cpanel.

My host suggests that it is a caching issue and if I perform a flushdns and clear my browser cache, this fixes the problem. But i am puzzled as to why it reoccurs.

Could there by something on the other server triggering it? Or is it just a matter of waiting a little longer for propagation?

Forgive me if the problem isn't clear. This stuff is not my forte.

Answer (score 2):

A 404 error indicates an error on the webservers side - not on the DNS level.  That means, that if you see a 404 error or the cPanel default site, DNS is working fine but the web server does not respond.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404#Overview

Check the web server logs and/or speak to your provider about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What was the [TTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Record_caching) before you made your changes? I've seen 86,400 seconds (one day) and 604,800 (one week) as common choices in the past. (The important number is what the TTL was set to *before* you made your change, as that dictates how long stale data is held in DNS caches.)

Comment: @p.ink, hrm, then all clients ought to have refreshed their caches by now. Can you find out what upstream DNS servers all your 'broken' clients are using? Perhaps you've got a DNS server that isn't reliably flushing its cache.

Comment: i'm not sure how to do that i'm afraid. sorry, our IT guy is away and I'm trying my best to deal with this issue.  how to find upstream dns?

Comment: @p.ink, many clients get their DNS servers from DHCP leases; check the network configuration on the broken clients for the DNS address they have been assigned, or were configured to use. You're liable to have two or three configured DNS machines if your organization is large enough to have an IT guy; one or more of the servers may be slow / broken. You can use `host www.abc 192.168.0.1` to query the DNS server `192.168.0.1` for what it knows about `www.abc`. Check all of the servers listed by all the clients that returned stale data.

Comment: thanks sarnold. the clients are spread out over different networks and in different countries so it will take some time to obtain this information, but at least we have an idea as what might be the cause. i will check this and post results.